# How to fix "Error: (-12646:0) Illegal MIME type: text/plain"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, mime-types, http-live-streaming

I am trying for HTTP Live Streaming. When i validating my master playlist , it gives me above error

I have segmented my video firstly with

> sudo /usr/bin/mediafilesegmenter -I -f Desktop/MyVideo Desktop/MyVideo.mp4

Segmented Audio only with

> sudo /usr/bin/mediafilesegmenter -I -f Desktop/MyAudio -a Desktop/MyVideo.mp4

After that i have created master playlist by using `variantplaylistcreator` and my final link is `http://www.example.com/Apple/final.m3u8`which contain video n audio only both stream.

When i validate this link with

> `mediastreamvalidator validate http://www.example.com/Apple/final.m3u8`

It gave me this out put

```
Playlist Validation: 

Error: (-12646:0) Illegal MIME type: text/plain

Segments:

    OK
```

How do i fix this error?? Any help?

Thank you in advance..!!

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information on what code and libraries you're using to load the playlist, what generates the playlist etc.

Comment: Thanx for response. I've edited code. May it helps to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your web server configuration such that it serves up the m3u8 file with the correct mime-type. According to [this list of playlist formats](http://gonze.com/playlists/playlist-format-survey.html#M3U), an m3u playlist (m3u8 is a UTF-8 variation of m3u) should have one of the following mime types:

> Mime type:
>
> audio/mpegurl (recommended)
>
> audio/x-mpegurl

In [this technical note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-WEBSERVERCONFIG) Apple say that `application/x-mpegurl` should be used so I think that's your best bet:

[image: Screenshot of Apple Technical Note]

Assuming you're using Apache (quite likely) [these instructions should help you configure the server correctly](http://www.flashcentral.com/Tech/Server/Apache.htm).

Comment: the link currently does not mention x-mpgeURL only vnd.apple.mpegURL.  can this cause problem if it's x-mpeg?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing It maybe they've dropped support or something, but would seem unlikely. Give it a try I guess!